# docker mapping volume directory not showing up

Tags: docker

When I map a directory it doesn't show up in my docker container.
I am on docker 1.11.2 on Mac using toolbox.

```
calloway$ docker -v
Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9
calloway$ ls -ltr /tmp/foo/
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 calloway  wheel  0 Jun  8 09:21 regularfile.txt
calloway$ docker run -it -v /tmp/foo:/mytmp -w /mytmp ubuntu bash
root@26fc182f7964:/mytmp# ls
root@26fc182f7964:/mytmp# exit
```

More exploration: /tmp mapped is /tmp on "default" Virtual Machine.

```
Joshuas-MBP:~ joshuacalloway$ docker-machine ssh default
                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/
 _                 _   ____     _            _
| |__   ___   ___ | |_|___ \ __| | ___   ___| | _____ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __| __) / _` |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ \ '__|
| |_) | (_) | (_) | |_ / __/ (_| | (_) | (__|   <  __/ |
|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|_____\__,_|\___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|
Boot2Docker version 1.10.3, build master : 625117e - Thu Mar 10 22:09:02 UTC 2016
Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd
docker@default:~$ mkdir /tmp/OnDefaultVM
docker@default:~$ touch /tmp/OnDefaultVM/myfile.txt
docker@default:~$ exit
Joshuas-MBP:~ joshuacalloway$ docker run -it -v /tmp/OnDefaultVM:/mytmp -w /mytmp ubuntu bash
root@1184ff43dc88:/mytmp# ls
myfile.txt
```

Comment: Ok, it's got something to do with docker toolbox, and default VM.

Comment: What does `echo $DOCKER_HOST` respond with, and what does /tmp/foo look like on that machine?

Comment: btw, after using "docker beta for mac", I don't see this issue anymore